# Vue, v-bind: Passing data as a property

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to pass data as a property in a component. v-bind is required, but i can't seem to make it work. Error is one line 3 in the HTML, the v-bind directive doesn't work and returns an error: "Custom elements in iteration require a "v-bind:key" directive"

```js
<script>
export default {
    name: "ChatLog",
    props: {
    },
    components: {ChatMessage},
    data() {
        return {
            messages: [
                {
                    message: "Hey",
                    user: "James"
            },
            {
                message: "Hola",
                user: "Jimmy"
            },
            ]
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

```html
<template>
    <div class="log">
      <ChatMessage v-for="(message) in messages" v-bind:message="message"> </ChatMessage>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this (The key is required in a loop):

```
<template>
    <div class="log">
       <ChatMessage
           v-for="(message, key) in messages"
           v-bind:message="message"
           v-bind:key="key"
       ></ChatMessage>
    </div>
</template>
```

Btw, you may use shorthand alternative for `v-bind` like this:

```
<ChatMessage v-for="(message, key) in messages" :message="message" :key="key" />
```

Also, if message is unique, then you may use the `message` as the value for `key` like this:

```
<ChatMessage v-for="message in messages" :message="message" :key="message" />
```

*Note: Read more about the [key](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Maintaining-State) here.*

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a key for the given element in the for loop.

```
<ChatMessage v-for="(message) in messages" v-bind:message="message" :key="message"> </ChatMessage>
```